# iOS insertSubview:belowSubview: crashing with SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a custom `TabbarViewController` that basically hides the standard tab view. I attached a button that, when pressed, will animate a menu to the screen. Everything works fine while using the application for long time, but at some point it will crash with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` or a `SIGABRT`.

Curious thing is when i added a `NSLog` for printing `tabbarController` and `menuView` just before checking if menuView is a subview of `tabbarController`, it crashed on the `NSLog` line (to me looks like one of them is released but there is no explicit call and they both are retained).

This crash never happened on the simulator. Any ideas on what's wrong?

**AppDelegate.h**

```
UIButton *ribbon;
RibbonMenu* menu;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CustomTabbarController* tabbarController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView* menuView;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
@synthesize tabbarController;
@synthesize menuView;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
tabbarController = [[CustomTabbarController alloc] init];
    [tabbarController setTabBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    tabbarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: EventsNavigation, StyleNavigation, BrandNavigation, MemberNavigation, settingsNavigation, nil];

    ribbon = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [ribbon retain];
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"toppart.png"];
    [ribbon setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    ribbon.frame = CGRectMake(234,0,86,97);    
    //MENU SELECTOR
    [ribbon addTarget:self action:@selector(didClickMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [tabbarController.view addSubview:ribbon];

    self.window.rootViewController = tabbarController;    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


- (void) didClickMenu {
    if (!menuView) {
        menu = [[RibbonMenu alloc] init];
        menuView = menu.view;
        menuView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [blinkTimer invalidate];
        ribbon.selected = NO;
    }

    if ([tabbarController.view.subviews containsObject:menuView]) {
        [self removeMenu];
    } else {
        menuView.frame = CGRectMake(235,-370,82,432);
        //**CRASH HERE**
        [tabbarController.view insertSubview:menuView belowSubview:ribbon];
        [UIView transitionWithView:menuView
                          duration:0.2
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                        animations:^ { menuView.frame = CGRectMake(235,0,82,432);}
                        completion:nil];
    }
}

-(void) removeMenu {
    [UIView transitionWithView:menuView
                      duration:0.2
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                    animations:^ { menuView.frame = CGRectMake(235,-370,82,432);}
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {[menuView removeFromSuperview];}];
}
```

This is the crash log

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x35a5388f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33677259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35a53789 +[NSException raise:format:] + 1
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35a537ab +[NSException raise:format:] + 35
4   UIKit                           0x33313cf1 __windowForView + 157
5   UIKit                           0x33155ccd -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 21
6   UIKit                           0x3315680d -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1169
7   UIKit                           0x33172071 -[UIView(Hierarchy) insertSubview:belowSubview:] + 29
8   MyAppName                       0x000c6af3 -[AppDelegate didClickMenu] (AppDelegate.m:247)
```

Comment: Where do you ever add ribbon as a subview? You're attempting to add menuView below it, but is it in your view hierarchy?

Comment: @rdelmar Edited question. Ribbon is added in didFinishLaunching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are assigning the value to `menuView`, you are not using property but yo are using iVar of `menuView`.

To use the property, you should assign the value to menuView by using self.

```
self.menuView = menu.view;
```

By accessing property, it will retain it. By accessing iVar, it will not retain it. So there are chances that, once you remove the `menuView` from its `superView`, it will get removed.

```
- (void) didClickMenu {
    if (!menuView)
    {
        menu = [[RibbonMenu alloc] init];
        **self.menuView = menu.view;**
        menuView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [blinkTimer invalidate];
        ribbon.selected = NO;
    }
 }
```

Comment: sorry, I thought it was enough to accept the answer ^^' Here you go and thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This crash should happen on the simulator as well. In `didClickMenu` you try to access menuView. However, from what it looks like, you don't have an instance variable named menuView. You have a **property** called menuView, but you need to call this property using `self.menuView`.

Alternatively, if you're using Xcode 4.4 or higher and you don't synthesize your properties, the compiler will create an instance variable for you. This instance variable has the same name as the property, but with a _ prefix--in this case it would be `_menuView`.

Comment: Sorry about that, both properties are synthesized. Added to the edited question

Comment: You should still access them via the setter methods, not directly. You're bypassing any memory management by using ivars directly.

Comment: @jrturton That's a good point, but this shouldn't be related to the question's crash

Answer (score 1):

I hold the opinion that the key is the **coding-style**.

Are ribbon and menu global? Whether or not, you don't own menu, instead you just assign menu.view to menuView, not using self.menuView to retain. Yes, I know the code just alloc menu  without releasing it.

It's hard to happen on the simulator running on a Mac, but maybe easier on a iPod touch with less memory and poor ability.

As we know, EXC_BAD_ACCESS is due to accessing released object.
If I were you , I would :

1. Update the Xcode to the newest version.
2. Don't write any @synthesize code for property. Xcode will @synthesize menuView = _menuView.
3. Avoid using global variables if possible, using property in OOP instead. So, I would write `self.menuView = [[[RibbonMenu alloc] init] autorelease];` to own the RibbonMenu's view for use.

FYI : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html